# Using non-continuous integers as identifiers in cells or structs in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, struct, cell, identifier

I want to store some results in the following way:

```
Res.0 = magic(4);      % or Res.baseCase = magic(4);
Res.2 = magic(5);      % I would prefer to use integers on all other
Res.7 = magic(6);      % elements than the first.
Res.2000 = 1:3;
```

I want to use numbers between 0 and 3000, but I will only use approx 100-300 of them. Is it possible to use 0 as an identifier, or will I have to use a minimum value of 1? (The numbers have meaning, so I would prefer if I don't need to change them). Can I use numbers as identifiers in structs?

I know I can do the following:

```
Res{(last number + 1)} = magic(4);    
Res{2} = magic(5);
Res{7} = magic(6);
Res{2000} = 1:3;
```

And just remember that the last element is really the "number zero" element.

In this case I will create a bunch of empty cell elements `[]` in the non-populated positions. Does this cause a problem? I assume it will be best to assign the last element first, to avoid creating a growing cell, or does this not have an effect? Is this an efficient way of doing this?

Which will be most efficient, `struct`'s or `cell`'s? (If it's possible to use `struct`'s, that is).

My main concern is computational efficiency.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just store *two* cell arrays, one with the "index" and the other with the data at that index? Or a single cell array with two columns? Or a struct array with two fields?

Comment: @wakjah. Most of all because I haven't thought of it, i guess =) I'm trying to visualize how this would work, but I'm not really able to do so. I don't see how it will be any different. Can you give an example of how I can store the zero-element this way? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to [EitanT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16895366/1714410), it sounds like [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab)'s [map containers](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/map-containers.html) are exactly what you need. They can deal with any type of key and the value may be a `struct` or `cell`.

**EDIT:**

In your case this will be:

```
k = {0,2,7,2000};
Res = {magic(4),magic(5),magic(6),1:3};
ResMap = containers.Map(k, Res)

ResMap(0)    
ans =
16     2     3    13
 5    11    10     8
 9     7     6    12
 4    14    15     1
```

Comment: I can't say anything about the speed (vs. Eitan's answer), but it's definitely the sort of thing I'm after! Thanks!! =)

Comment: If you're using simple keys such as integers, a map reduces to a simple array. There's really no need to overcomplicate.

Comment: @EitanT, your approach is probably better performance-wise (only marginally though). On the other hand, I think using a `map` is much easier to understand. This is only relevant if others will need to use the same code, though.

Comment: Parts of the code will, in time, be translated to C (not by me), so readability is a factor. I don't know about C, but if I remember correctly, `map` works the same way in C++ at least. (Of course, in C I can use 0 as an index, but `map` seems to be a good approach nevertheless =)

Comment: In that case I would recommend using map containers in matlab as well. The performance penalty for using maps is probably negligble if you only plan to use ~300 keys. Any C/C++ programmer will immediately understand the functionality of a map. If readability for other people is important, I'd say the less matlab-magic the better (even though @EitanT's trick was pretty cool!).

Comment: I stumbled over this question, and I recall that I actually used your solution! So, your answer is finally accepted =) (Sorry for unaccepting @EitanT =))

Answer (score 5):

Let's review your options:

#### Indexing into a cell arrays

MATLAB indices start from 1, not from 0. If you want to store your data in cell arrays, in the worst case, you could always use the subscript `k + 1` to index into cell corresponding to the *k*-th identifier (*k* ≥ 0). In my opinion, using the last element as the "base case" is more confusing. So what you'll have is:

```
Res{1} = magic(4);                   %// Base case
Res{2} = magic(5);                   %// Corresponds to identifier 1
...
Res{k + 1} = ...                     %// Corresponds to indentifier k
```

#### Accessing fields in structures

Field names in structures are not allowed to begin with numbers, but they are allowed to contain them starting from the second character. Hence, you can build your structure like so:

```
Res.c0 = magic(4);                   %// Base case
Res.c1 = magic(5);                   %// Corresponds to identifier 1
Res.c2 = magic(6);                   %// Corresponds to identifier 2
%// And so on...
```

You can use [dynamic field referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) to access any field, for instance:

```
k = 3;
kth_field = Res.(sprintf('c%d', k)); %// Access field k = 3 (i.e field 'c3')
```

I can't say which alternative seems more elegant, but I believe that indexing into a cell should be faster than dynamic field referencing (but you're welcome to check that out and prove me wrong).

Comment: Thanks so much Eitan!  Do you know if I should set the size of the cell before I start, i.e. `Res = cell(3000,1);`, similar to what I would do I was inserting elements at the end of vectors? Or won't this have any effect, since the size of each cell is unknown anyhow?

Comment: It's always better to preallocate memory than let MATLAB dynamically increase the size of the array, as the latter is usually _much_ slower.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the idea in @wakjah 's comment. If you are concerned about the ***efficiency*** of your program it's better to change the interpretation of the problem. In my opinion there is definitely a way that you could **priorotize** your data. This prioritization could be according to the *time* you acquired them, or with respect to the *inputs* that they are calculated. If you set any kind of priority among them, you can *sort* them into an structure or cell (structure might be faster).

So

```
Priority    (Your Current Index Meaning)    Data
   1        0                               magic(4)
   2        2                               magic(5)
   3        7                               magic(6)
   4        2000                            1:3
```

Then:

```
% Initialize Result structure which is different than your Res.
Result(300).Data = 0; % 300 the maximum number of data
Result(300).idx = 0; % idx or anything that represent the meaning of your current index.

% Assigning
k = 1; % Priority index
Result(k).idx = 0;    Result(k).Data = magic(4);    k = k + 1;
Result(k).idx = 2;    Result(k).Data = magic(5);    k = k + 1;
Result(k).idx = 7;    Result(k).Data = magic(6);    k = k + 1;
...
```

Comment: Thanks @pm89! Sorry for the late reply. I agree, this looks like a neat way of doing it =) +1!